# adb glob expansion

Tags: adb, shell

I'd like to be able to issue:

```
adb pull storage/self/primary/Documents/*20220204* .
```

Right now doing that gives:

```
zsh: no matches found: storage/self/primary/Documents/*20220204*
```

Comment: You could emulate ADB pull using tar on device side, pipe everything using ADB exec-out to the PC and there untar the received stream. Would be pretty complex but would allow wildcards as it uses tar.

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [Why the file path the phone tells me, I couldn't find in `adb shell`?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/66212/44325) (ignore the title since it's actually asking about `adb shell` and `adb pull`)

Answer (score 0):

The matching of `*` wildcards is failing, because it's being done by zsh on your *computer*, which can't see your Android device's filesystem. It's looking for `storage/self/primary/Documents/*20220204*` in your computer's filesystem, and not finding it. It's fortunate that it doesn't exist on your computer, since if it did, it could only provide a source of confusion.

Here's a way to do the job with `tar`, using the `/data/local/tmp` directory, which you can write to from the adb shell on any Android device.

## Create some example data

`adb shell "cd /data/local/tmp; echo FileA > a.tmp; echo FileB > b.tmp"`

We've created `a.tmp` and `b.tmp` in `/data/local/tmp` on the device.

## Collect the data into an archive file

`adb shell "cd /data/local/tmp ; tar cvfz archive.tar.gz /data/local/tmp/*.tmp"`

The first use of `/data/local/tmp` is getting to the place where you'll create the archive; the second one is the location of the files you want to put into your archive.

## Get the archive out of the Android device onto your Linux machine (or is it macOS?)

`adb pull /data/local/tmp/archive.tar.gz .`

## Extract the archive into your current directory

`tar xvf archive.tar.gz`

## Delete the archive off the Android device

`adb shell "rm /data/local/tmp/archive.tar.gz"`